# Android make bitmap opaque against background color

Tags: android, xamarin

Given a bitmap, I know how to make an ImageView more transparent by setting alpha.  But I want to also set a white background color (different from the view its sitting on), so it appears more opaque than transparent.

Referring to the image below,

> I get the left pic using , ImageView.SetBitmapImage(bitmap).
>   Using ImageView.SetAlpha = 0.5, I get the middle pic
>   but how do I get the right pic.

[image]

Also, in my axml, I have set the ImageView background color to white, but it still doesn't help...I still get the middle pic.

```
     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: in the xml of your layout set the background white , the alpha is good

Comment: I have that, and it doesnt work ;(

Comment: If you call `SetAlpha()` on the `ImageView`'s `Drawable` instead, you'll save yourself the extraneous `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @MikeM.Great, thanks! That worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by wrapping the ImageView in a LinearLayout, where the backgroundcolor was set to white.  Then the bitmap alpha was fine